# how to change a character array in typedef struct from a function?

Tags: c, function, struct, typedef, strcpy

i'm trying to change array a inside set of typedef through function readset but it doesn't do anything to it
and im trying to understand how to use a pointer so i would just send it to the function but its not working 
how to do that?

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct set {
    char a[128];
}set;

 set SETA={""};

void readset (set rset)
{
    char tmp[128];
    int i;
    i=0;
    while(i<128)
        rset.a[i++]='0';
    i=0;
    while(i<128)
        tmp[i++]='0';

        tmp[arr[1]-1]='1';
    strcpy(rset.a, tmp);
    printf("tmp in function is: %s\n",tmp);

}

int main()
{
    int i=0;

    while(i<128)
        SETA.a[i++]='0';
    printf("\n");
    printf("setA before: %s\n",SETA.a);
    readset(setPtr);
    printf("setA after: %s\n",SETA.a);

return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Please make a [mre]. setPtr is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a struct, defined like this:

```
typedef struct bar_s
{
    char data[128];
    int someInt;
} bar_t;
```

You would define your function like this:

```
void foo(bar_t* p) //Note the asterisk
{
    strcpy(p->data, "Hello!"); //copy a string into data field
    p->someInt = 0; //assign value to someInt field. Note the "->"
    (*p).someInt = 0; //Same as above, using a dereference operator.
}
```

Now how do you pass a pointer to this function? You would do something like this:

```
bar_t sample;
foo(&sample); // & = address-of operator.
```

Your readSet function needs a bit of work to get it functional, but that's how to work with pointers in C. In your case you would do something like this:

```
void readSet(set* rset)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 127; ++i)
    {
        rset->a[i] = '0';
    }

    //Note that all strings in C must be terminated with a null character.
    //So, let's put one at the last place in the array.
    rset->a[127] = '\0';
    ...
}
```

Comment: so my understanding is i must use a pointer from that kind of typedef in order to change a variable inside the struct
And the mistake i did with the last bit of the string array of not putting null
Thanks i got it !

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to define a separate pointer named `setPtr` and assign the address of `SETA`, just before calling the function `readset`, like;

```
set *setPtr = &SETA;
readset(setPtr);
```

or, just send the memory address of the `SETA` to `readset`;

```
readset(&SETA);
```

Btw, you may need to change the function decoration as well, like;

```
void readset (set *rset) {
    ...
        rset->a[i++]='0';
    ...
}
```

In addition, you may use a string terminating character (`\0`) at the end of your char array in order to get the `printf` & `strcpy` functions do their task properly.

Answer (score 1):

structs and unions are passed by the value so you can: https://godbolt.org/z/3NUWHW

1. Pass it by value

```
struct str
{
  char a[100];
  int x;
  /*  ... */
};

struct str read_a(struct str s)
{ 
   strcpy(s.a, "Test");
   return s;
}

int main()
{
   struct str s;
   s.x = 5;
   s = read_a(s);

   printf("s.a=%s, s.x=%d\n",s.a,s.x);
}
```

2. Pass by pointer

```
struct str
{
  char a[100];
  int x;
  /*  ... */
};

struct str *read_a(struct str *s)
{ 
   strcpy(s->a, "Test1");
   return s;
}

int main()
{
   struct str s;
   s.x = 6;
   read_a(&s);

   printf("s.a=%s, s.x=%d\n",s.a,s.x);
}
```